# MySQL group_concat with limit and joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
# tb_shops

shop_id PK
shop_name

# tb_products

product_id PK
product_name
shop_id FK
```

I need to list all 'shops' with 4 products but some shops has more than 4 products.

I tried this query:

```
select a.shop_id,
        a.shop_name,
        count(b.product_id) as ptotal,
        group_concat(c.product_name separator ',') as products 
from tb_shops a 
left join tb_products b on a.shop_id=b.shop_id 
left join (
    select product_name,shop_id 
    from tb_products 
    limit 4) as c 
    on a.shop_id=c.shop_id 
group by a.shop_id 
order by a.shop_name asc
```

But, it doesn't work properly. It returns duplicate products. If I use `distinct` in `group_concat` it doesn't come with 4 products of the shop, really strange... someone knows a better solution?

Comment: The subquery returns any 4 rows from the table, not 4 rows for each shop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group for how to get 4 records for each group.

Comment: I see some people saying about substring_index, but i think that is performance hit cuz maybe some shop can have 500 items or 1000 and substring_index will only limit the output but these 500 items will come in query

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no really great solutions for top-N per group in MySQL, so you have to choose the least of evils.

Answer (score 0):

> Well i need to list all 'shops' with 4 products but some shops has
>   more than 4 products

You could use the `having` keyword and get rid of some `joins`

```
select a.shop_id,
       a.shop_name,
       count(b.product_id) as ptotal,
       group_concat(b.product_name separator ',') as products
from tb_shops a
join tb_products b on a.shop_id = b.shop_id
group by b.shop_id
having count(b.product_id) = 4
order by a.shop_name asc;
```

This will fix your issue. Basically what yo do here is do a normal `join` on botch table, then `group` by `shop_id` and finally only select those whose `count` of group is equal to 4. No need to use two left joins here.

Comment: well this query will show more than 4 products, look the having